# What does “9s 3d“ mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

I am reading a British story for ESL learners and I can't understand the abbreviations 9s, 3d in the
sentence below.

Example: These queues have large cards that say: Queue here for 4s 6d; Queue here for 9s 3d; Queue here for 16s 8d.

Comment: What's the title of the story? Please include the source IN the question, not in the comments.

Comment: [*Why Does the Other Line Always Move Faster?*](https://books.google.it/books?id=fWDVBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA111&lpg=PA111&dq=%22These+queues+have+large+cards+that+say%22&source=bl&ots=v5fiAYB1nS&sig=ACfU3U2XFlSDQULWKXlSe6ubFz2LlwAy0g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiV8--L8PDrAhWD_aQKHYdjBtgQ6AEwAXoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22These%20queues%20have%20large%20cards%20that%20say%22&f=false)

Comment: This is an American book; the British wait in queues, not lines, and I suspect (as I hinted below) that the prices were invented.

Comment: This is from the 1946 book "How to be an Alien" by Hungarian immigrant to the UK, George Mikes.  To account for inflation, multiply by 50.

Answer (score 7):

16s 8d means 16 shillings and 8 pence.

In the old British currency (pre-1971) there were 12 pence in a shilling and 20 shillings in a pound.

Comment: Yeah, that's... a pretty strange thing to give an ESL student to read! Most people in the UK (under 60 anyway) probably wouldn't recognise those as prices, or know how to read them.

Comment: But why would people *queue* for these sums of money? The cards have different prices so people know where to stand in line.

Comment: I don't know, but based on the link you found, perhaps the queues are for different kinds of seats, and you pay extra if you want to sit in a better part of the auditorium.  I've never seen such signs myself, but of course, this would have been a half-century ago.

Comment: "Perhaps"... definitely. I remember these signs from my youth. The prices seem a little high; I remember in my teenage years boys and girls used to go for cinema "snogging" sessions in the "one-and-nines", and decimalisation came along when I was 18. The  "one-and-nines" were the seats at the back that cost one shilling and ninepence.

Comment: @cactustictacs - "Most people in the UK (under 60 anyway) probably wouldn't recognise those as prices, or know how to read them." - those who read "books" especially novels, may well know about things that happened or were invented before about the year 2000.

Comment: "snogging" sessions in the "one-and-nines" - the Camberwell Odeon - summer 1968 - showing "The Graduate" - it was about some guy, I think.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey oh sure, I'm just saying that the average person here is probably pretty unfamiliar with pre-decimal currency, and especially how it was written. I didn't want the OP to feel bad for not recognising those as prices when, honestly, most British people probably wouldn't either!

Answer (score 2):

As the other answer has indicated, it's a reference to the pre-1971 British [£sd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%A3sd) currency system.

- **£** (from Latin *libra*) = pound
- **s** (from Latin *solidus*) = shilling = 1/20 of a pound = 5p in modern decimal currency
- **d** (from Latin *denarius*) = penny (pl. *pence*) = 1/240 of a pound

The notation Xs Yd means X shillings + Y pence.  In modern terms,

- 4s 6d = 22½ p
- 9s 3d = 46¼ p
- 16s 8d = 83⅓ p

Of course, due to inflation, the prices would be an order of magnitude higher today.

As for *why* people would queue (or AmE “line up”) for specific prices, it's likely in the context of them entering a play, concert, or sporting event, where different portions of the theatre/stadium have different ticket prices.

In my personal experience (as an American), it's far more common for such signage to indicate section/row numbers instead.  However, if a venue is “general admission” (no assigned seats) except for being segregated by ticket price, then the price-based signage would make more sense.

Comment: To account for inflation, multiplying by about 50 gives a rough estimate:  so 4s6d is about £11.25,  and 16s8d over £40 - expensive for a cinema ticket